# Redirect all outbound SSH traffic through single IP from bunch of AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I have one host which restricts SSH access to it from a list of allowed IP's.

On bunch of AWS EC2 instances I have a worker apps which attempts to establish SSH connection with my host. Number of EC2 instances will be changing in future and I don't want to configure my host every time.

Is there a simple way to redirects all of outbound SSH traffic through single machine with one IP?

Comment: You could run a proxy on one of the instances and direct other instances to use that proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at a NAT gateway?

Put your EC2 instances in a private subnet, route all traffic from the private subnnet to 0.0.0.0/0 thru the NAT, and that should solve your problem.

Update:
The NAT gateway is a managed service, which replaces the NAT instance. NAT gateway can scale up to 45Gbps.  Each NAT gateway gets an Elatic IP per subnet.

Comment: Do I need separate EC2 instance for hosting NAT gateway? Can it be done by any other AWS service?

Comment: Or maybe examples of such configuration?

Comment: No NAT Gateway is the newer offering that replaces NAT Instance. You only need to deploy an "instance" (hence the name) for NAT Instance.

Comment: @AntonMedvedev - it's all [documented](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat.html)